# VB.NET How to create a reminder by checking database saved dates

Tags: mysql, vb.net, date, datetime, visual-studio-2015

I have this few line of codes where I save the date from datetimepicker to my database column REMINDER.

```
myCommand.CommandText = "Update kup_table SET REMINDER = @reminder Where ID = @theIDD"
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reminder", DateTimePicker1.Value.Date)
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theIDD", theID)
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

In my database, the date is saved in this format **2015-12-14 00:00:00** since the datatype is DATETIME.
How do I compare it with the date now? If the saved date and today date are a match, then a reminder will go off.
I have tried using this sql command but having still having trouble where the reminder is always zero. Thanks in advance.

```
myCommand.CommandText = "Select COUNT(*) from kup_table Where REMINDER BETWEEN DATE() AND DATEADD('d', 1, DATE())"
mySqlConn.Open()
Console.WriteLine("Connected.")
count = myCommand.ExecuteScalar()
MsgBox("You have " + count.ToString + " reminder(s).")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Select COUNT(*) from kup_table Where DATE(REMINDER) = DATE(NOW())`

The `DATE()` function returns the date part of the datetime only. (e.g. 2015-12-14)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Works like a charm ;)